# Unable to display the graticule with OpenLayers 3

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

This issue is more a javascript problem than an OpenLayer one. I guess...

The sample just work fine with my own WMS server : http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/examples/graticule.html

In my project, the 'map' object is set in the map.js file, loaded in the index.html before the graticule.js file. It displays the map, as expected.

```
var map = new ol.Map({
    layers: [
        new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
        })
    ],
    target: 'map',
});
```

Now my very simple code in graticule.js

```
"use Strict";
var graticule = new ol.Graticule();
graticule.setMap(map);
map.getViewPort().style.cursor = 'crosshair';
```

Ok now the fun part : 
I can see the crosshair (SO the map object is ok!), but the setMap(map) just throw an error "TypeError : a is null" in the debug console.

I'm not a Javascript expert so it can be a relatively dumb reason.

Please, help, I'm stuck.

Comment: Just before your `graticule.setMap(map)` do a `console.log(map);` and check your console to see if it's loaded yet.  If it's in separate files, then it might also not be in scope.  You should post both files.

Comment: As I said, the map object is in scope because I can change the cursor. And the map.js contains the very basic snippet to create an OpenLayer map with one layer. If I log the map object, I can see its properties (in the minified form with a, b, c, d variables, is it a clue ?)

Comment: can you please post all code? so we can create a jsfiddle and debug it.

Comment: Here is the map.js code !

Comment: Where is your map's View? also it seems to be working fine for me:
https://jsfiddle.net/timh06/hsnLLmz7/

Comment: It works fine because all the javascript code is in one file. My problem is when using two separate files for the map declaration and the graticule. I don't know how to emulate that on jsfiddle, that's why I didn't submit one here !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

I used ol.proj.Projection in the view property, but I need to use directly the string projection code :

```
var view = new ol.View({
    center: center,
    zoom: 6,
    projection: 'EPSG:4326'
});
```